# Front End / Sample Data Incomplete?

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, installation, not-found

Decided to check out Magento, so I downloaded the `sample data` and `Magento CE`. I installed the sample data and CE locally using `WAMP`.

Everything went smoothly, but when I go to view the frontend, it seems the ***main images are missing***(see below). Also any links I click on, I ***get a `Not Found` message***:

`Not Found Error` looks like this :

> The requested URL /magento/accessories/eyewear.html was not found on this server.

Anyone else have a similar problem in the past? I'm perplexed as to how to correct this?

I tried reinstalling but got same result.

Thank you for your time. George

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### About Image Problem

Most probably, you may forget to merge the folders that is available in sample data (media, skin) folder with Magento's default `media`, `skin` folder. If you didn't do that, please merge those folders.

If you did that step, then you need to check the permission of `media` folder. You need to have both `read & write` (777) permission for this folder. Set that permission to `media` folder.

### About Page Not Found Problem

Most probably, it is `modRewrite` issue. First you need to  check whether this url works for you

```
 /magento/index.php/accessories/eyewear.html
```

Please note the insertion of `index.php` inside the url. If the above url actually "finds" the page, then it is surely a `modeRewrite` issue. You can fix it using following steps.

**step 1:** Go to to your site root folder and you can find the `.htaccess` file there. Open it with a text editor and find the line

```
#RewriteBase /magento/.
```

Just replace it with

```
RewriteBase /
```

**step 2:** Then go to your admin panel and enable the Rewrites(set yes for Use Web Server Rewrites). You can find it at

```
System->Configuration->Web->Search Engine Optimization.
```

**step 3:** Remove all cache of your site. For this, remove all content that comes inside `var/cache` folder. Don't worry about this step.It is safe. This is where magento cache files are hold.

For more details, [**go through this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474740/how-to-remove-index-php-from-urls).

Comment: Happy to help you. If my answer helped you to resolve your problem, then feel free to accept it.

Comment: Still having issue with the Page Not Found. Still working through it

Comment: you tried url that I have described ?

Comment: Yes. That url worked. Went into .htaccess and made the change you suggested. Rewrites were already enabled. Deleted contents inside of var/cache. PNF still persist.

Comment: made changes in admin section. ie `System->Configuration->Web->Search Engine Optimization.` also do a cache refresh through `system > cache management`

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after I added the following file to the `/etc/httpd/conf.d` directory:

magento.conf

Alias /mage /var/www/html/magento

```
<Directory /var/www/html/magento>

    Options FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride all

     RewriteEngine On

 </Directory>
```